# Yii duplicating fields dynamically and validating

Tags: validation, yii

I have my validation rules in my model like so:

```
public $name;
public $email;

public function rules() {
return array(
// name, email
array('name, email', 'required'),
// message
array('nameconfirm, emailconfirm, message, referrerID, referrerName', 'safe'),
);
}
```

In my view I then have:

```
<div>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'name', array('name' => 'name[]', 'class' => "form-input" )); ?>
<small<?php $model->getError('name') ? " class='error'" : '' ?>><?php echo $form->error($model, 'name'); ?></small>
</div>

<div>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'email'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email', array('name' => 'email[]', 'class' => "form-input " )); ?>
<small<?php $model->getError('email') ? " class='error'" : '' ?>><?php echo $form->error($model, 'email'); ?></small>
</div>
```

Then with some Javascript I clone these fields by selecting a button.

My question is how can I change my code so it validates every time the name and email are duplicated?

For example sometimes I may just have 1 x name - email then selecting a button it could be 2 x name - email. This could go up to 10 or even more.

At the moment, only the first "name" and "email" are validated.

I believe this is because my attribute is being duplicated so it will only validate 1 attribute. Would it be possible to use a for each in the model?

Any suggestions would really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is tabular input collecting: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table 
However, this will help you on server side, the client side validation won't work unless you create a custom validation for your tabular input.